# IE Issue with jQuery and JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, shopping-cart

I'm trying to write a function that transfer the items from the basket and push it in the cart.
The problem I am facing at the moment is that although this code works fine in Firefox and Chrome it isn't recognising the products.

```
var modals_pool = {};

$('.deal_order_btn').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    deal = {};
    deal.id = $(this).attr('deal_id');
    deal.title = $(this).attr('deal_title');
    deal.items = [];
    additional_total = 0;
    $(this).parents('.deal_item_holder').find('table.deals_item_').each(function (index, ele) {
        item = {};
        item.id = $(ele).attr('deal_item_id');
        item.name = $(ele).find('.deal_item_name a').text();
        if ($(ele).find('select.product').length) {
            item.product = $(ele).find('select.product').val();
        }
        if ($(ele).find('select.product').length === 0) {
            item.product = $(ele).find('.deal_item_name a').attr('rel');
        }
        if ($(ele).find('select.size').length) {
            item.size = $(ele).find('select.size option:selected').text();
        }
        if ($(ele).find('.static_size').length) {
            item.size = $(ele).find('.static_size').text();
        }


        deal_object = modals_pool[$(ele).attr('container_id').replace(/ /g, '_') + "_" + $(ele).find('.product').val()];

        //console.log(deal_object);

        if ($(ele).find('select.product').length && deal_object) {




            item.product_name = $(ele).find('select.product :selected').text();

            item.product_topping = deal_object.selected_topping_normal;
            item.base = deal_object.default_base;


            item.product_double_topping = deal_object.selected_topping_double;


            item.product_total = deal_object.total;
            additional_total += deal_object.total;



        }


        deal.items.push(item);

    });



    deal.total = $(this).parents('li:first').find('span.customize_total_deal').text();
    deal.orginal = $(this).parents('li:first').find('span.customize_total_deal').attr('orginal_total');
    deal.addtional_topping_total = additional_total;

    $.post(window.location.href, {
        'action': '_saveUserDeal',
            'deal_details': JSON.stringify(deal)
    }, function (data) {
        if (data.code) {
            var date = new Date();
            var milseconds = date.getTime();
            $('.basket_box_holder').load(root + store_name + '/get_cart?' + milseconds);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? The `live()` method has been deprecated since 1.7 and removed in 1.9

Comment: please feel free to visit this link for the live version : http://topspizza.co.uk/public/acton/deals/

Comment: What do you mean by "*isnt recognising the products*", which part of the script does not work as expected? I can only guess that IE refuses to parse all those custom (and invalid) HTML attributes.

Comment: Well the Title gets added and the cost, but the products dont.

Comment: so the product gets added to basket but if you visit checkout in IE you will see errors instead of product names.

Comment: maybe this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/interactive10/eJzyq/10/

Comment: Arash Kiani, can you mark Joco Koster has an acceptable answer if it is the case?

Answer (score 1):

Your script breaks on line 683 with the error:

> Object doesn't support this action

This is because item is a reserved keyword in Internet explorer 8 and below, try renaming it to something else OR use the var keyword to locally declare item. This will probably fix it:

```
var item = {};
```

Cheers.