# Show/Hide JavaScript not working in IE, only in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the show/hide script I found online. When you click on the "view menu" image it's supposed to show the hidden `div` for each section. I'm not getting it to display/expand on Internet Explorer for some reason but it works fine in Firefox.
http://www.abatchoflove.com

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function unhide(divID) {
        var item = document.getElementById(divID);
        if (item) {
            item.className = (item.className == 'hidden') ?'unhidden':'hidden';
        }
    }
</script>
```

And this was the CSS portion.

```css
<style type="text/css">
    .hidden { display: none; }
    .unhidden { display: block; }
</style>
```

This is what the code looks like in the sections.

```
<td valign="top" bgcolor="#51BEB7">
    <a href="javascript:unhide('cookiesmenu');">
        <img src="images/cookies_nav.gif" border="0" usemap="#Map2">
    </a>
    <div id="cookiesmenu" class="hidden">
        <img src="images/cookies_menu.gif">
    </div>
</td>
```

Would love it if I could get a little help... Or if there is another way to go about it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suggest you use jQuery or another javascript library to handle this for you, since they all make significant effort to maintain cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: i'd try changing the style attribute directly:
item.style.display = "block"; vs item.style.display = "none";

Comment: It appears to me like your `javascript:unhide('cookiesmenu')` for the href is not executing in IE.  I'd suggest you switch to an event hander rather than a `javascript:` URL.  I don't know for a fact that that is the issue in IE, but regular event handlers work just fine in IE and a breakpoint in IE in your `unhide()` function is not  being hit at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

`<a onclick="unhide('cookiesmenu')">`

instead of

`<a href="javascript:unhide('cookiesmenu');">`

Comment: <a onclick="unhide('cookiesmenu')"> seemed to have worked. Thank you very much everyone, it's the first time i post something online and i'm blown away with the quick replies.

Answer (score 0):

A Internet Explorer reserved word has been used as an identifier (function or variable name).

change **item**  by another variable name and give it a try.

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1.1

http://www.springenwerk.com/2009/01/is-reserved-word-in-internet-explorer-6.html

[IE Issue with jquery and JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068589/ie-issue-with-jquery-and-js/15070989#15070989)

If you want to test first if this is your issue, here is your script with a different variable name.

```
function unhide(divID) {
    var MyItem = document.getElementById(divID);
    if (MyItem) {
        MyItem.className = (MyItem.className == 'hidden') ? 'unhidden' : 'hidden';
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GvKLX/1/

Note that 'inlined javascript' is tending to disapear for security reasons. So you should consider reforming your code using javascript libraries such has jQuery. Meaning, even javascript events like 'onclick' are to become obsolete.

Comment: But, the function isn't even called in IE10.

Comment: Try the jsFiddle provided with my answer in your IE10 and come back tell me what happens. Also, if you can provide the console error log, it will GREATLY help.

Comment: I'm not the OP.  I just observed that the unhide function was not called in IE in the OP's page (breakpoint in it not hit).  A [modified version of your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/gRmx2/) using the variable named `item` just like the OP has works just fine for me in IE10.  So, clearly something else is going on in the OP's page and this doesn't seem to change anything.  Also, frieder's answer seemed to have fixed the issue for the OP.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for confirming. I cannot test for myself at the moment and will modify answer for a suggestion.